# Uppercase Theta in 'mtpro2'

Tags: mtpro

I am trying to type an uppercase theta symbol with the `mtpro2lite` package, but it doesn't appear properly, in its place is a black box. I moved the `times` package after and it appeared, but the numbers are all in the Computer Modern family. Is there any way that I can solve this problem?

Here is the MWE:

```latex
\documentclass[fleqn]{book} % It's just the environment I'm working with, it shouldn't matter.
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{times}
%\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algcompatible}
\usepackage{hvlogos}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{breqn}

\begin{document}
Theta: $\Theta$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: it would be a lot easier to help if you showed an example, a complete  document with `\begin{document} theta $\Theta$\end{document}` and whatever preamble is required to show the issue and without all the unrelated packages. latex will not drop characters with no warning, what does the log show?

Comment: dvips warns 
' TeX output 2023.01.14:1145' -> dd256.ps
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/tex.pro>
</home/davidc/texmf/dvips/l3backend/l3backend-dvips.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/enc/dvips/base/8r.enc>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/texps.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/special.pro>
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/dvips/base/color.pro>. 
</usr/local/texlive/2022/texmf-dist/fonts/type1/urw/times/utmr8a.pfb>[1
dvips: **Warning: missing glyph \`Theta'**
]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not really related to `mtpro` and not related at all to most of the packages shown. `times` is an obsolete package dating from the 1980s, use `newtxtext` for a more complete times clone.

[image]

```
\documentclass[fleqn]{book} % It's just the environment I'm working with, it shouldn't matter.
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
%\pdfmapfile{=mtpro2.map}
\usepackage[lite,subscriptcorrection,slantedGreek,nofontinfo]{mtpro2}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage[noend]{algcompatible}
\usepackage{hvlogos}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{mdframed}
\usepackage{breqn}

\showoutput
\begin{document}
Theta 123: $\Theta 123$.
\end{document}
```

Comment: It works well for me, problem solved!